# Can't left click links in a bootstrap dropdown menu. Have to right click and open in new tab

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I have a dropdown menu made with the Bootstrap V3.3.7 dropdown menu control that is populated with several links, but these links only work if I right click and open in new tab. If I left click, nothing happens. No errors on the console and no network activity. Obviously they are valid links since they work if I try to open them in a new tab.

My HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li *ngFor="let item of safeUrlPair(button)">
        <a class="dropdown-item" [href]="item.value">{{ item.key }}</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Part of the Typescript:

```
safeUrlPair: () => [{ key: 'Link Text', value: this.object && this.object.id ? this.getSafeLink(`${this.objectLink}${this.object.id}`) : '' }
```

The getSafeLink method:

```
getSafeLink(link: string): SafeUrl {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(link);
}
```

I have come up with a workaround that doesn't quite work, but it's progress.

New HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li *ngFor="let item of safeUrlPair(button)">
        <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="triggerLink(item.value)">{{ item.key }}</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

And the triggerLink function:

```
triggerLink(url: string): void {
   if (!url) {
     return;
   }

   window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

This allows the left click to work and opens a link in a new tab, but since it is a safeURL, the url isn't passed as a typical link, like http://www.google.com would be.

It ends up being something like: http://localhost:4200/SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20https://www.google.com%20(see%20http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Comment: I have the same issue, have you come up with a reason why it is failing ?

Comment: @Elbarto I wasn't able to come up with a good solution, but I threw something hacky together by using the triggerLink method from above and just split that SafeUrl a couple times as a string value to get my desired link, like so: url = url.toString().split('SafeValue must use [property]=binding: ')[1];
    url = url.split(' (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)')[0];

Comment: Alright, well i found why it wasnt working for me, i had an e.preventDefault() messing around very deep in my javascript. It was a pain in the ass to find..